# Calculating distances from one reference point to multiple points in one shp file

Tags: point, distance

I am a total novice to GIS; I read some of the answers to similar posts, still have difficulties to do it. I am not that familiar with GIS or QGIS and am looking for a step by step approach.

Here is what I am asking to be clearer:
I have individual animals with ID, date of observation, and location of observation in decimal degrees in a xl sheet. Some individuals have been observed several times. I would like to get distances in km between the first observation location and all subsequent observations (for example, an animal was seen in 2005 at point xy, and then again in 2006 at x1y1, and in 2015 at x2y2. I am trying to find the distance between xy and x1y1, and xy and x2y2 for all individuals where I have >2 observation locations). I made shapefiles from the xl sheet by using the xy coordinate function, so the shapefile works, just do not know how to calculate the distance, if I can do it from one shapefile, or if I need 2 files (original location as file 1 and all subsequent locations in a separate shapefile?). I hope this is clearer.

My file (1 shp file) consists of 100s of individuals (they have IDs) and observation locations. So an individual has been seen at point a, b, c, d. I am interested in getting all distance values for each individual's observations from a reference point (usually the first observation point) (i.e., ind 1 was seen at a, b, c, d, so I would like to get distances for a-b, a-c, a-d.

I have created 2 new shape files now; one with the first location, the second with all subsequent locations of the individuals. When I use the point distance tool and use the original location layer as first layer and the subsequent locations as the second layer no table with distances is calculated. I tried also to use the OD matrix and used the original file with all locations but this file was not accepted into the tool window. Do the attribute tables have to have a specific format with date and time, locations, etc? I really need somebody who can guide me through this step by step or if there is a tutorial youtube that would help. All the other answers are already too technical for me especially when they go ito the code-writing.

How do I go about this?

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Please [edit] your question and add the relevant tag.

Comment: Please also summarize what methods you've tried so far, and where you got stuck. Include links to the posts you tried to follow.

Comment: You wil need to iterate through the layer with    location_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(Your_layer)[0]
            locate_data = location_layer.dataProvider()
            points = location_layer.getFeatures()
            
            for point in points:   #find your initial point             
                if point_a_id == point['ID']:
                    point1 = point

            points = location_layer.getFeatures()            
            for point2 in points:   #iterate through all points
           
                distance = QgsDistanceArea()

Comment: Is it acceptable to find the solution solely in Excel?